# Distribution of reversed k-th order statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X_1,...X_n$ be i.i.d. Let $Y_{(i)}$ the $i$-th order statistic of that sample. The distribution function of the order statistic is given by

$$F_{Y_{(i)}}(y) = \sum_{k=i}^n \binom{n}{k} y^k (1-y)^{n-k}.$$

How would that distribution function change if the sample is ordered in descending order instead of ascending (i.e., $Y_1 > Y_2 > \cdots > Y_n$)?

Comment: First off, your distribution function assumes that $X_i \sim U(0,1)$ (which is not a big restriction). As to your question, if, say, $n = 5$ and $Y_{(2)} = .3$, what do you think is $Y_4$ (using descending order)? Do you see what is going on?

Comment: Change of names. that's all.

Comment: On RHS $y$ must be replaced by $F(y)$ (don't read this is as an answer to your question).

Comment: "Let $F$ be iid with a sample of a set of $X_i$, $i=1,\ldots,n$." That is badly written if anything can be.  If you meant "Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ by i.i.d.", then you should say something like that.  Your later use of capital $F$ is not consistent with the usage you seem to try to establish at the outset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Y_1<\cdots<Y_n$ are what you get when you sort $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ into increasing order and $W_1>\cdots>W_n$ are $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ sorted into decreasing order, then $W_i=Y_{n+1-i}$.  So the distribution of $W_i$ is the distribution of $Y_{n+1-i}$.

Your notation seems confused.  One could write $X_{(i)}$ for the $i$th order statistic from the sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, or one could write $Y_i$ for the same thing, but why write $Y_{(i)}$?  Moreover, your final question omits the parenthesized subscripts.

Comment: Thanks! That was it. I also edited my post according to your suggestions.